# Azure IoT Central Publish Error Something went wrong Error Code: 400.470.006.319 / 2093ej9xx7l.4

Tags: azure, iot, azure-iot-hub, azure-iot-edge, azure-iot-central

I am trying to publish my device template, but I am always getting the error "Something went wrong Error Code: 400.470.006.319 / 2093ej9xx7l.4". Please see the preceding image. May I please know what could be the reason? This is [the doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-central/core/howto-set-up-template) I am following.

[image]

Comment: Sir what is the benefits of writing articles on C# Corner?

Comment: Sir please tell me.

Comment: Sir please tell me. i am see you online Yesterday.

Comment: @kumar please message me on any social media.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix this issue. The issue was because of that I had two `Interfaces` and one of them was not having any capabilities in it.

[image]

After deleting this unwanted `Interface`, I was able to successfully publish my device template.

[image]

I think it would have been much easier to resolve this issue if we get related error information instead of some random error codes.